# Getting not proper error code form R using Rserve with c++ client

Tags: r, rserve

I have this part of code:

```
Rconnection *rc = NULL;
rc = new Rconnection();
int stat=rc->connect();

Rmessage *msg=new Rmessage();
Rmessage *cmdMessage=new Rmessage(CMD_eval, "sumwe(2,3)");
int res=rc->request(msg,cmdMessage);
int r = CMD_STAT(msg->head.cmd);
```

as you can identify I have specified wrong R function name sumwe. For this I got in Rserve console by saying "Error: could not find function "sumwe""

But while checking value in r i.e `CMD_STAT(msg->head.cmd);` getting 127(hex 7f). I am expecting `#define ERR_unsupportedCmd   0x49 /* unsupported command */` or 
`#define ERR_unknownCmd       0x4a /* unknown command */` - the difference.`

Please help me what I am doing wrong.

details:

```
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Rserve version  0.6-8 (338)
Platform Windows(32bit). Rserve running locally.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ERR_unsupportedCmd` refers to the Rserve QAP1 protocol, i.e. commands like `CMD_eval`. You are sending a valid command `CMD_eval` so Rserve is not complaining -- the error is in R so regular R rules apply. As far as Rserve is concerned R aborted the evaluation. If you want the R error back, you can use `try({...}, silent=TRUE)` and you get an error as an object of class `try-error` containing the error string.